# OBIEE installation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, business-intelligence, obiee

I was trying to install OBIEE 11g Oracle Business Intelligence, on windows 7, But when my installation reached the 13th step out of 14, any error appears indicating that coreapplication obis1 has failed !!
I followed this solution but  still I can't start the weblogic server.

https://arunsadagopan.wordpress.com/2013/12/06/opmnctl-start-coreapplication_obis1-fails/

Any help would be appreciated?!?! 
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 isn't and wasn't ever a supported operating system since it's a desktop OS and not a server OS.

tl;dr: If you need an environment for learning and testing, get the SampleApp images whcih have everything you want + loads more:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-foundation/obiee-samples-167534.html